# Advice to connect remote VM using python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to connect VM using below process :-

1. Open remote desktop connection windows app
2. click on shared pool
3. Enter credentials

Once I login, I need to open web-browser in VM and do some processing. As of now, I am able to connect to VM ( with some issue ) but I don't know how to open VM. I can't install any new software in my VM. My VM is based on Windows 11. May I know whether it is achievable from host computer using selenium/python.

Please note that I have browsed some of the topic where people advised to use SSH,Putty but I can't use those ways.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're using program A to do something, but you want to do it programmatically using program B. There are several ways of achieving what you want, but neither is as simple as you might've hoped.

- You could find information if there's an API for the program you're using, or just use similar protocol, like VNC for example. This might require installing additional software on VM.
- You could run the program straight from the VM, but this also assumes installing python on VM.
- You could intercept packets going to VM to run it in local browser instead, but this might not bring the desired effect as I'm not sure Selenium would work with it.

That's everything that comes to my mind. If you could share more details about what you're trying to achieve maybe we'd find a simpler way.